# ajax post data from javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

Im trying to send a dict from javascript code to a python script via ajax through post. Heres the js:

```
    function foo(){
      context = {
         'var1': val1,
         'var2': val2
       }
       $.ajax({
         url:'/pyfoo'
         type: 'POST'
         data: context,
         success: function(){
            ...
         }
       });
```

I need to pull var1 and var2 from context in python but it doesn't come through. Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried a few thing in python:

```
def pyfoo():                                                                 
  data = json.loads('context')
```

Comment: Are you `json.loads` ing the string you get in Python? How are you getting it?

Comment: @JaredSmith, I've tried with json but I know very little about json. i get errors such as: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: `json` is essentially just a format for serializing a string-keyed hashmap as a string. Meaning you have to deserialize it when it gets where its going. It also seems that its not getting encoded by the client code, try `data: JSON.stringify(context),`

Comment: Huh? `json.loads('context')`? Why are you referencing the name of a client side variable in your server side code? What HTTP server are you using?

Comment: see python function should take up the JSON response by using function handlers. def function(handler): print handler.get_arguments or so... let me know if I'm wrong. generally tornado/django frameworks takes something like this.. whenever ajax called that url handler function will simple do the work for you. What framework you are using?

Comment: This may be obvious, but is your Python code running inside a web server of some kind? Like Apache, Flask, or something like that?

Comment: So what is supposed to replace 'context' is the confusing part for me. And it is running in Flask

Comment: `data = json.loads( request.data )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [flask examples on their site](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/60711/flask.request.data) :

```
def pyfoo() : 
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.data)
        print(data)
        return "Success" 200
    except ValueError:
        error('Unable to parse JSON data from request.')
        return "Error" 400
```